# Is the sentence, "He has been in Delhi for three years" present perfect tense?

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect

Let's take a sentence.

**He has been in Delhi for three years**.

What is the meaning of this sentence? *He moved to Delhi 3 years ago and still he is there right*? Now what if I consider this sentence to be a **present perfect tense**? We know that the structure of present perfect tense is subject+has/have+past participle. Now past participle form of the verb '**be**' is '**been**' . So can this sentence be a present perfect tense? If this is present perfect then the meaning is different. The meaning will be **he has an experience of being in Delhi for three years** (*maybe from 2012-2015*). I'm totally confused. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly deduced, this sentence is indeed present perfect. And as you also correctly stated, it would mean *he moved to Delhi 3 years ago and is still there*. That is because you used "in", which implies that he is still there now. "He has been *to* Delhi for three years" would mean *at some point, he was in Delhi for three years*. However, this is not very idiomatic. If you want that meaning, the typical way of saying it would be "He was in Delhi for 3 years [at a specific time]".

Comment: I don't think anyone would say "He has been to _somewhere_ for three years".

Comment: And what about the deduction ' he has an experience of being in Delhi for three years maybe from 2012-2015 and he is now somewhere else ' ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey true, you're more likely to say "I was in *somewhere* for three years" and possibly specify when that happened.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is present perfect. The structure defines that.

While it's true that *some* present perfect sentences refer to an experience in the past, *not all* present perfect sentences have that function. Present perfect has several other functions, including *"event that started in the past and continues until now"*, which is the function it has in this sentence.

More functions of present perfect include:

- something that happened in the past and may happen again: "*He has written several books.*"
- something that happened in the past and has a result in the present: "*I haven't eaten yet today.*"